# Provide custom labels and metadatas on VM instances via running Dataflow job on Google cloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

Does anybody know how to provide custom labels and metadata on VM instances via running Dataflow job on Google cloud?

So I tried to run Java Dataflow job I want to set some custom labels and metadata on VMs that serve this job.

UPDATE:
create https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6832

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Dataflow does not support giving labels to VMs. You can give labels to your job by specifying them in the `DataflowPipelineOptions`, but I don't think these get added to the VMs.

To add labels to your job, try:

```
private DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(DataflowPipelineOptionsImpl.class); 
options.setLabels(ImmutableMap.of("key", "value"));
```

Comment: Yep, you are right, it doesn't apply to VMs labels.